# Python pdfminer not showing utf-8 characters properly

Tags: python, utf-8, pdfminer

I'm extracting text in french from PDF using pdfminer and python. The problem is that I don't see the accents like éàã... etc.

For example:

*on  se  place  (ce  qu'il  faut  faire)  sur  le  terrain  social,  la  famille qu6becoise  demeure  au fond  ce  qu'elle  n'a jamais  cess6  d'Etre, malgr6  certains bouleversements  apparents.  Les  donn~es  sociales  et  familiales  qu6becoises  ne sont  pas  les  donnes  francaises.*

The command I'm using is:

```
pdf2txt.py -c utf-8 sample.pdf
```

I've installed CJK Languages, but still doesn't work. 
I'm running python 2.7.10.

Any suggestion on how to properly display the characters ?

Comment: Maybe the characters are badly represented in the PDF already. If you open the PDF in a viewer, highlight some text with accents and copy-paste them somewhere else: are "é", "ç" etc. displayed properly then?

Comment: You're right... there's an issue in the PDF. Thank you.